# How to error rather than warning on specific rule

Tags: swiftlint

I want the build to error out on `trailing_whitespace`. I have added `trailing_whitespace: error` to my `.swiftlint.yml` but it's still just showing up as a warning.

I've seen [How to force error on SwiftLint instead of warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406844/how-to-force-error-on-swiftlint-instead-of-warnings) but that's about treating *all* warnings as errors, I want just selectively treat some rules as errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in your .swiftlint.yml file:

```
trailing_whitespace:
  severity: error
```